# Filter OR in UA Query Explorer

Tags: filter, google-analytics

We use the OR operator in our request (according to this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters).
The request is OK in the Demo & tools (https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/) with one filter : ga:keyword==XXXXX
But the request is KO with OR : ga:keyword==XXXX,ga:keyword==YYYYY

Error code: 400
Error message: Invalid value 'ga:keyword==XXXX , ga:keyword==YYYYY ' for filters parameter.

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this operator `=~` that means *Contains a match for the regular expression*.

So the value of the filter have to be like this:

```
ga:keyword=~XXXX|YYYYY
```

Comment: You're welcome. Mark answer as solved,  pls